# Resharper: Can I control where Completion/Intellisense pops up?

Tags: resharper, intellisense

When I am typing in Visual Studio with Resharper enabled, I start typing a function call and it brings up the following popups (see the image below).

Now that's  a lot of useful information but not when it is completely obscuring the code around it.

Is there any setting I can use to make this info pop up... somewhere else?  Like on the edge of the screen or something.  I really need to be able to read what's around it.

This is Visual Studio 2022 17.6.0 with the very latest version of Resharper, 2023.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot move these popups but you can do a few things to mitigate their impact:

- Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to remove them.
- Turn off Parameter Info: `ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`IntelliSense`->`Parameter Info`, untick 'Automatically show parameter info in 0 milliseconds'
- Reduce the completion list length: `ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`IntelliSense`->`Completion Appearance`, set 'Completion list has X rows' to a smaller number.
- Make completion list transparent by pressing and holding the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key down.

Comment: Thanks.  Found those.  Was really hoping for a way to move them.     I will make a feature request with Resharper